# Bokeh plot not displaying correctly

Tags: bokeh

I am using Bokeh plots in a couple of my Django views.  The plots are rendering the data correctly, but they are weirdly skewed when rendered on my page.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-center"> Resource Usage </h4>
  {% for label,div in divs.items %}
    <h3 class="text-center"><u> Satellite {{ label }}</u></h3>
    </br>
    <div class="container">
      {{ div | safe }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{{ script | safe }}
```

Where the `div` code looks like this:

```
'<div class="plotdiv" id="b367d397-25cc-4fa2-9b92-e0d0a8f155fa"></div>'
```

I'm just trying Bokeh's base example [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/setup.html) but am getting something that looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why that offset is happening?

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion on Bokeh's Google group, the problem was that I applied CSS styling to tables that I have elsewhere in my page and that was affecting how the Bokeh plots were being displayed.  Once I removed the table styling the plots displayed correctly.