# Bokeh map not respecting div size

Tags: html, css, django, bokeh

I want to embed a map using my Django application. Next to Bokeh, I'm only using Bootstrap.

This related post doesn't have an answer that helped me:
[Bokeh plot not displaying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833193/bokeh-plot-not-displaying-correctly)

Annoyingly, the map does not respect the size of the bokeh div. When inspecting the elements, I can see that the figure exceeds the div. Removing css templates from Bootstrap does not seem to solve the problem. The surrounding HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
Here's a table...
</table>                
<div class="bk-root">
<div class="plotdiv" id="6b1ee173 etc..."></div>
</div> </div>
```

[image: This result]

Any idea's about what's wrong? Let me know if I need to supply more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is really hard to solve without having the website to play with, I guess it is a css issue, try to give the `plotdiv` `width: 100%`

Comment: Yeah I know, unfortunately I cannot give public access. I tried the 100% in the css, but it didn't work.

Comment: An issue on this was also opened on the Bokeh google group. Bryan van de Ven, lead developer of Bokeh replied:

"Hi, dev build 0.12.5dev11 is available which appears to fix the issue:

http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/geo.html

Several other outstanding GMap issues also fixed (reset tool, updatable map options, blanking on refresh)

Thanks,

Bryan" .

Comment: @ballenpiraat, great to hear that there's a fix for this. But can I also get the include files for the dev version? Currently I'm using the bokeh CDN...